# TeamCity and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, teamcity

I have a NUnit test project in which I have a simple test method that uses WebDriver to find an element on the page.

I can run the test method in VS2015 with no problem. Then I try to build this project in TeamCity (9.1.6) with a build step like this:

```
Runner type: NUnit
NUnit runner: NUnit 3
Path to NUnit console runner: packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.2.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe
```

I get the following error when TeamCity tries to perform the build step:

```
[Web.Test.FindPage] OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:64963/session/27d5b5b821e3b90c9d6f8183f05a3d05/element timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
```

Both TeamCity Server and Agent are configured as Windows services that run under a service account.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I can't run the build agent as a Windows service. I have to run it in a console. Problems solved once I did that.

Comment: More information about it in TeamCity documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-Configureautomaticbuildagentstart